# Custom grouping in ag-grid for Date values

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, ag-grid

I use an ag-grid to show grid-data. I have a column for showing date. The actual value is stored in format (**YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS**). I also implemented custom filter to filter this column only by date, not including the time (**YYYY-MM-DD**) and a custom renderer to show the date in defined format(**YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm**). The example is presented below:

[image: Row values and filtering]

The problem is currently with grouping. The grouping is done relatively to the initial value, which is in format (**YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS**). The issue is presented below:

[image: Grouping issue]

And I would like to group not by the whole date, but for days for example, like in my filter. Is there a possibility to achieve that?

Comment: Could you show your gridoptions (column defintions, renderer) ? This could help me.